# How do I re-enable my displays?

Tags: display

I have three monitors attached to my GPU. They were all working perfectly fine. Then I went to Settings/Displays and disabled two of them since I just wanted to watch a movie and wanted to try that instead of just turning them off.

Now they have completely disappeared from my settings (although the remaining one is still numbered 2) and I cannot re-enable them!

They are not disabled in the BIOS and, in fact all screens come on when the machine boots including at the logon screen. But as soon as I log in, two of them turn off.

Does anybody know how to get those back?

I'm on fully up-to-date Ubuntu 20.04.3.